# What does SNIOKAH mean?

Tags: props, bodyguard

Spoilers for anyone who hasn't watched Bodyguard TV Series yet.

In the last episode, David Budd is seen going on a trip with family and the license plate of his car reads SNIO KAH.

Does this hold any special meaning? The camera lasted a while on the shot, so I am guessing it does.

[image: snio kah]

I googled the phrase but I only got Twitter hashtag [#sniokah](https://mobile.twitter.com/hashtag/sniokah?lang=en). Someone tweeted that this was a great way to end the series, so it should mean something. I am not from UK, perhaps it means something there. Does anyone know what it means?

Comment: It means it was registered in Edinburgh in 2010... idk if that has any significance [haven't seen it yet]

Comment: It just looks like a standard UK license plate. I'm not aware of any particular meaning to SNIOKAH (outside of the show, which I haven't watched), and there don't seem to be any anagrams hidden in it (unless they relate to the show). I don't think the license plate itself has any particular relevance here. The hashtag might have been chosen because it would (presumably) only be relevant if you've seen the ending of the show, and would therefore avoid spoiling it for those who haven't.

Comment: or you could have been searching SN eye oh, rather than SN ten - Reg is valid & real, Blue Qashqai, Reg'd Edinburgh Aug2010 - https://www.regit.cars/car/sn10kah & others confirm, inc https://www.webuyanycar.com/Valuation/VehicleLookup

Comment: Funniest is the comment on https://rate-driver.co.uk/SN10KAH ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin  Weird as I did try both versions! Either way - good spot in the rate driver link!

Answer (score 8):

It's simply a pool car owned by or leased to the production company.

I guess there are times when a vanity plate (or something with some meaning) might be used, but I don't think this is the case here.

It's just a car, and the registration number isn't significant at all in the plot.  The series doesn't use symbology like this - everything in the series is driven by the plot.

Comment: There is slight significance, but only in so much as the character is Scottish & he drives a car with a Scottish plate. Minor minor point, but it shows someone in action cars was paying attention.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a particular word, but an actual license plate number.

This may seem like SNIO KAH, but actually it's SN 10 KAH, where SN represents Edinburgh area (S for Scotland and N for Ediburgh as mentioned [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicle_registration_plates_of_the_United_Kingdom#Local_memory_tags)). The way it was written may have confused you. Like I saw a license plate with 8055 written like BOSS in [Aarya 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arya_2).

[image: Screenshot from Arya 2 movie showing 8055 written as BOSS]

You can find more details about this car [here](https://rate-driver.co.uk/SN10KAH).

From above page,

> Official local mnemonic: Scotland
>
> Postal area: Edinburgh
>
> Issued: between march 2010 and august 2010
>
> Blue Nissan Qashqai, manufactured in 2010, first registered on 1 August 2010. Cylinder capacity: 1598cc, CO2 emissions: 155 g/km.

Comment: This makes sense, except that your 'Boss' example DOES actually say 'BOSS', not 8055!

Comment: Actually it's 8055. It is just written that way.

Answer (score 0):

The UK has no vanity plates- it looks like a perfectly valid plate for a car registered in 2010 between March and September 2010 - according to the [Wikipedia article on it.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicle_registration_plates_of_the_United_Kingdom)

Chances are it was just a random car, possibly belonging to someone on the production company, or a rental that fit their needs.

I would guess it's a great end not cause of the license plate number but the ending itself.

Comment: Hi there, the UK *does* have 'vanity plates' but we call them 'personalised plates' - see https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=personalised+number+plates+uk